# salvar uma lista de objeto

Tags: java, java-ee

Eu possuo um objeto chamado mensagem e um outro chamado frames.. Ou seja, na minha aplicação eu posso ter uma lista de frames relacionado a mesma mensagem. Eu já tenho essa lista no meu `ManagedBean`, agora eu preciso salvar esses frames, mas antes, preciso salvar esse objeto mensagem. 
Como posso fazer isso?

Aqui está o código do meu ManagedBean, na qual agora desejo salvar:

```
public void insert() {

    try {

        System.out.println(" --- " + listAllFrames.size());

        if (message.getName().equals("")) {

            MessageGrowl.warn(MessageProperties.getString("message.verify.title"));

        } else if (message.getCategory() == null) {

            MessageGrowl.warn(MessageProperties.getString("message.verify.category"));

        } else if (message.getType() == null) {

            MessageGrowl.warn(MessageProperties.getString("message.verify.type"));

        } else if (listAllFrames == null) {

            MessageGrowl.warn(MessageProperties.getString("message.verify.frame"));

        } else {



            message.setUser(user);

            messageFacade.save(message);



            MessageGrowl.info(MessageProperties.getString("message.sucessoMessage"));

            clear();

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie a lógica para salvar um frame e depois faça:

```
messageFacade.save(message);
for(Frame f: listAllFrames){
   frameFacade.save(f);
}
```